# OdbcCommand on Stored Procedure - "Parameter not supplied" error on Output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, odbc

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure (against SQL Server 2005 through the ODBC driver) and I recieve the following error:

> Procedure or Function 'GetNodeID' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

@ID is the OUTPUT parameter for my procedure, there is an input @machine which is specified and is set to null in the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNodeID] 
@machine nvarchar(32) = null,
@ID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Nodes WHERE NodeName=@machine)
BEGIN
    SELECT @ID = (SELECT NodeID FROM Nodes WHERE NodeName=@machine)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Nodes (NodeName) VALUES (@machine)
    SELECT @ID = (SELECT NodeID FROM Nodes WHERE NodeName=@machine)
END
END
```

The following is the code I'm using to set the parameters and call the procedure:

```
        OdbcCommand Cmd = new OdbcCommand("GetNodeID", _Connection);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@machine", OdbcType.NVarChar);
        Cmd.Parameters["@machine"].Value = Environment.MachineName.ToLower();

        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Int);
        Cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _NodeID = (int)Cmd.Parameters["@Count"].Value;
```

I've also tried using Cmd.ExecuteScalar with no success.  If I break before I execute the command, I can see that @machine has a value.

If I execute the procedure directly from Management Studio, it works correctly.

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: What value does your ID parameter have while debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing :

```
OdbcCommand Cmd = new OdbcCommand("GetNodeID", _Connection);
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

With :

```
OdbcCommand Cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call GetNodeID(?,?)}", _Connection);
```

More info :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310130

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by

> there is an input @machine which is
>   specified and is set to null in the
>   stored procedure

In your proc's signature, this line:

```
@machine nvarchar(32) = null
```

doesn't mean that you're setting `@machine` to null inside the proc - it means you're assigning a default value to be used in case the parameter is missing (in this case, `null` is the value to be used for a missing param).

Getting the error about `@ID` being missing would happen if you were calling this stored procedure without passing any parameters at all (`@machine` would not be flagged as a problem since it has a default value defined).  Your code example looks fine to me - are you sure the stored proc isn't being called from somewhere else in your program (somewhere where no parameters are being added)?

Comment: But while debugging, the @machine parameter has a value it seems.

Comment: @Veer: I think Moe's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Stored procedure with input parameters and ODBC Connection:**

**create a stored procedure:**

> create procedure proc_name  @parm1 varchar(20), @parm2 varchar(10) as begin insert into table_name values(@parm1,@parm2);end

---

This code works in `SQL Server.`

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = txtname.Text;
        string num = txtnum.Text;
        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("dsn=naveenk_m5");
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call proc1(?,?)}",con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@parm1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value=name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@parm2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = num;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("inserted a row");

    }
```