# Syntax error while trying to call an Oracle package using ODBC in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odbc, package

I'm trying to consume an Oracle 9i package using ODBC and C#. I've tried to use the syntax described in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310130), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949641/call-oracle-package-function-using-odbc-from-c-sharp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687187/what-is-the-proper-odbc-command-for-calling-oracle-stored-procedure-with-paramet) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799405/odbccommand-on-stored-procedure-parameter-not-supplied-error-on-output-param) but I can't seem to get it right.

***Note***: I'm **not allowed** to use ODAC/ODP.NET in this particular case.

This is the package structure:

```sql
DECLARE 

  PARAM1 NUMBER; --in
  PARAM2 VARCHAR2(200); --out
  PARAM3 VARCHAR2(200); --out
  PARAM4 VARCHAR2(200); --out

BEGIN

  PARAM1 := 123;
  PARAM2 := NULL;
  PARAM3 := NULL;
  PARAM4 := NULL;

TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3, PARAM4);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line(PARAM2);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line(PARAM3);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line(PARAM4);

COMMIT;
END;
```

This is how I'm calling the package:

```cs
string var1 = "123";
int var2;

OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=TESTHOST)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=TESTSID)));Uid=TESTUSER;Pwd=TESTPASS;");
cn.Open();

using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{ BEGIN ? := CALL TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC(?,?,?,?); END; }", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM1", OdbcType.Decimal).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["PARAM1"].Value = var1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM2", OdbcType.VarChar).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM3", OdbcType.VarChar).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM4", OdbcType.VarChar).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int.TryParse(cmd.Parameters["PARAM2"].Value.ToString(), out var2);
    uAcctStatus = cmd.Parameters["PARAM3"].Value.ToString();
    uReturnMsg = cmd.Parameters["PARAM4"].Value.ToString();
}

cn.Close();
return var2;
```

And this is the error message I'm receiving:

```sql
Exception: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

**EDIT**: I have tested the package and code and it works in ODAC/ODP.NET, but I was asked to change this to ODBC for another server. The troublesome part for me is:

```cs
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{ BEGIN ? := CALL TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC(?,?,?,?); END; }", conn)
```

Comment: Are you sure `TestFunc` is a function, not a procedure?  The PL/SQL call seems to indicate it is a procedure, not a function, in which case there is no return value.

Comment: @JustinCave I guess you are right. This is just one of the several syntax combinations I've tried to no avail. I understand it is a function which receives four parameters and returns one value.

Comment: If that were the case, your PL/SQL block should error out because you have no variable to store the result that would be returned from the function.  You can't call a function in PL/SQL without assigning the return value to something.

Comment: @JustinCave I want to store the return value in var2; I successfully did this using ODP.NET in another environment, but in this server I can only use ODBC

Comment: Initially, I'm just looking at the PL/SQL block you posted to call the procedure/ function.  That PL/SQL block is calling a procedure (there is no return value).  If that works, then you must be trying to call a procedure.  If the PL/SQL block you posted is throwing an error, then it makes sense that you really have a function because the PL/SQL block is not attempting to assign the return value of the function to anything.

Comment: I think you are confusing the ODBC call syntax.  remove the BEGIN..CALL... ; END; pieces or leave that in and remove the ODBC escape characters - {}.  So, try "BEGIN ? := TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC(?,?,?,?); END;"  or try "{  ? := CALL TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC(?,?,?,?) }"

Comment: Thanks @OldProgrammer, your comment made me realize a dumb mistake - I wasn't waiting for a return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work. I added the size of each parameter and made corrections to the call: the function has four parameters (1 in, 3 out) and no return value:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "{ CALL TESTUSER.TESTPKG.TESTFUNC(?,?,?,?) }";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM1", OdbcType.Decimal, 38).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["PARAM1"].Value = var1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM2", OdbcType.VarChar, 5).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM3", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM4", OdbcType.VarChar, 200).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I also found this document very helpful: [Using the Oracle ODBC Drivers with Third Party Products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/odbcfaq-128251.pdf)