# Using stored procedure with ODBC and MySql in C# and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures, odbc

The hosting where I am registered, does not support temporarily **MySql.Data.MySqlClient** using C# ASP NET and they cannot say when this will be possible.

The FAQ  suggests to use the **MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver** to connect to my mysql database and exec the stored procedure.

I have never used this type of ODBC connection in the past and in fact I get the empty return.

The output value from sProc is null.

The stored procedure on the MySQL database, using phpmyAdmin, working correctly.

The output value from sProc is 3.

I found many different suggestions on the web but without solving my problem.

How to do resolve this?

My code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OdbcConnection connection =
                    new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (OdbcCommand cmd =
                        new OdbcCommand("{Call s_sproc(?,?)}", connection))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin_dd", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out_userid", OdbcType.Char).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Connection.Close();

                        if (cmd.Parameters["@out_userid"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            int number = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@out_userid"].Value);

                            if (number > 0)
                            {
                                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert",
                                    "alert('" + number.ToString() + "');", true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert",
                                    "alert('null');", true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
}


DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`Sql_user`@`%` PROCEDURE `s_sproc`(
IN `pin_dd` VARCHAR(255), 
OUT `out_userid` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @out_userid := NULL;
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT DAY(t_Date) from t_table WHERE DAY(t_Date) = ',pin_dd,' INTO @out_userid;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
SET out_userid := @out_userid;
SELECT @out_userid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

```
@out_userid
3
```

**Update #01 -- Solution @AnandSowmithiran**

```
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection connection =
                new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OdbcCommand cmd =
                    new OdbcCommand("{Call s_sproc(?,?)}", connection))
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pin_dd", OdbcType.VarChar, 100);
                    cmd.Parameters["@pin_dd"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@out_userid", OdbcType.VarChar, 100);
                    cmd.Parameters["@out_userid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(getValue))
                    {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert",
                                "alert('" + getValue.ToString() + "');", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert",
                                "alert('null');", true);
                    }

                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
```

Comment: Instead of `AddWithValue()`, use the Add method and then set the value and the "direction" property, refer SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111654/14973743)

Comment: Also, you should be using ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thanks for help. Please see **update #01** in the question. Now I have error `String[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.`

Comment: You need to mention Size property for string parameter types, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.size?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thank you so much for help. Now the output value is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes to be done to get this working,

1. Add the Parameters to the stored procedure by calling the Parameters collection `Add` method, instead of the AddWithValue().
2. Mention the `size` of the `string` typed parameters
3. Instead of using ExecuteNonQuery, you should be using `ExecuteScalar`